# Nomad and port mapping

Tags: networking, consul, nomad

Nomad has three different ways to map ports:

1. Network stanza under group level
2. Network stanza under config -> resources level
3. port_map stanza under config level

What is the difference and when I should use which?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- First of all `port_map` [is
  deprecated](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/drivers/docker#deprecated-port_map-syntax),
  so you shouldn't be using that as part of task driver configuration.

  > Up until Nomad 0.12, ports could be specified in a task's resource stanza and set
  > using the docker `port_map` field. As more features have been added to the group
  > network resource allocation, task based network resources are deprecated. With it
  > the `port_map` field is also deprecated and can only be used with task network
  > resources.
  >
  > Users should migrate their jobs to define ports in the group network stanza and
  > specified which ports a task maps with the `ports` field.
- `port` in the group network stanza defines labels that can be used to identify the
  port in service discovery. This label is also used as apart of environment variable name
  that indicates which port your application should bind to.
- `ports` at the task level specifies which `port` from network stanza should be
  available inside task allocation/container. From [official
  docs](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/drivers/docker#deprecated-port_map-syntax)

  > A Docker container typically specifies which port a service will listen on by
  > specifying the EXPOSE directive in the Dockerfile.
  >
  > Because dynamic ports will not match the ports exposed in your Dockerfile, Nomad
  > will automatically expose any ports specified in the ports field.

#### TLDR;

So there is only one correct definition:

```
job "example" {
  group "example-group" {
    network {
      # Dynamic ports
      port "foo" {}
      port "bar" {}
      # Mapped ports
      port "http"  { to = 80 }
      port "https" { to = 443 }
      # Static ports
      port "lb" { static = 8080 }
    }

    task "task-1" {
      driver = "docker"
      config {

        ...
 
        ports = [
          "foo",
          "http",
        ]
      }
    }

    task "task-2" {
      driver = "docker"
      config {

        ...
 
        ports = [
          "bar",
          "https",
        ]
      }
    }

    task "task-3" {
      driver = "docker"
      config {

        ...
 
        ports = [
          "lb",
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Consider running this type of job file (with whatever images). Then you will get the following
port mapping between a backend and containers:

```sh
for port in $(docker ps --format "{{.Ports}}"); do echo $port; done | grep tcp | cut -d':' -f 2

# Dynamic ports 'foo' and 'bar'
# 25968->25968/tcp,
# 29080->29080/tcp,

# Mapped ports 'http' and 'https'
# 29936->80/tcp,
# 20987->443/tcp,

# Static port 'lb'
# 8080->8080/tcp,
```

Now, if you get inside `task-1` allocation/container and check env variables, then you
would be able to get values for allocated ports if your tasks need to communicate with
one another.

```sh
env | grep NOMAD | grep PORT

# NOMAD_PORT_bar=29080
# NOMAD_HOST_PORT_bar=29080

# NOMAD_PORT_foo=25968
# NOMAD_HOST_PORT_foo=25968

# NOMAD_PORT_http=80
# NOMAD_HOST_PORT_http=29936

# NOMAD_PORT_https=443
# NOMAD_HOST_PORT_https=20987

# NOMAD_PORT_lb=8080
# NOMAD_HOST_PORT_lb=8080
```

In order to make communication between services easier, it is better to use service
discovery, e.g. [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) (also from HashiCorp) and to make you
life even easier consider some sort of load balancer, e.g.
[Fabio](https://github.com/fabiolb/fabio) or
[Traefik](https://github.com/traefik/traefik). Here is a [nice blog
post](https://medium.com/hashicorp-engineering/hashicorp-nomad-from-zero-to-wow-1615345aa539)
from HashiCorp's Engineer about it.

Comment: It might be good to mention that you can atill map ports using the "bridge" nettwork mode, enabled by the CNU plugins. (eg https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/integrations/consul-connect)

Comment: @jeroentbt I think it's more of a networking stanza subtleties and does not relate to port mapping that much. But I appreciate the effort.